# How to show all tab-pane on large screen and toggle on small screen Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

How do I make all tab-pane visible simultaneously in large screen and toggleable in small screen.

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <header class="header d-flex justify-content-center">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active show" id="instructions-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#instructions" role="tab"
                aria-controls="instructions" aria-selected="false">Instructions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="code-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#code"
                role="tab" aria-controls="code" aria-selected="false">Code</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="test-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#test"
                role="tab" aria-controls="test" aria-selected="true">Test</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </header>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="instructions" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="instructions-tab">
Instruction
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="code" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="code-tab">
code
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="test" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="test-tab">
test
          </div>
        </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Is there anything like `tab-pane-sm` or for small screen changes in bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a solution using bootstrap. Alternatively, using jQuery here is a possible solution, you can use the resize event on window, and detect a change of resolution. Then use the detach method to display in the tabs or to display in the same div at the same time :
I created this code based on yours , you can test it out with zooming with CTRL keys and scroll with the mouse  …

```js
function resisePage(){

  if (window.innerWidth <= 696) { //Detect mobile 

    $('#low_resolution_placeholder').css('display','block');
    $('#hight_resolution_placeholder').css('display','none');

    //check how many tabs were selected to be moved
    //console.log($('#hight_resolution_placeholder > div').length);

    for(const tab of $('#hight_resolution_placeholder > div')){  
      $(tab).append(
        $(`#placeholder_${tab.id}`).detach()
      );
    }

  }else{ //Detect other higher resolution screens

     $('#low_resolution_placeholder').css('display','none');
     $('#hight_resolution_placeholder').css('display','block');


     //check how many tabs were selected to be moved
     //console.log($('.tab-content > .tab-pane').length);

     for(const tab of $('.tab-content > .tab-pane')){  
       $('#hight_resolution_placeholder').append(
         $(`#placeholder_${tab.id}`).detach()
       );
     }

  }
}

resisePage();//run once on page load


//then attach to the event listener
window.addEventListener('resize',resisePage);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


        
        <section id="low_resolution_placeholder">
                <header class="header d-flex justify-content-center">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active show" id="instructions-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#instructions" role="tab"
                aria-controls="instructions" aria-selected="false">Instructions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="code-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#code"
                role="tab" aria-controls="code" aria-selected="false">Code</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="test-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#test"
                role="tab" aria-controls="test" aria-selected="true">Test</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </header>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="instructions" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="instructions-tab">
          
          <div id="placeholder_instructions">
Instruction
  </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="code" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="code-tab">
                    <div id="placeholder_code">
code
  </div>

          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="test" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="test-tab">
                    <div id="placeholder_test">
test
  </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        <section id="hight_resolution_placeholder">
        </section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You may need to use Expand snippet to see the effect.

Comment: It didn't work in some instances

Answer (score 0):

As I recently know that this tab-pane is present in tab-content which is responsible for the changing tab and showing content. Then the solution for me is

Add id to where tab-content present

```
<div id="main-container" class="wrapper tab-content">
```

```
function resisePage() {

  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    $("#main-container").addClass("tab-content")
  } else {
    $("#main-container").removeClass("tab-content")

  }
}
resisePage()
window.addEventListener('resize', resisePage);
```